# 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Tags: reactjs, module, styled-components, es6-modules, commonjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9jE5.png)
This problem occurred while importing createGlobalStyle from styled-components.
I also tried adding "type": "module" to the package.json file, but nothing meaningful.

[ GlobalStyle.jsx ]

```
    import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
// eslint-disable-next-line
import React from 'react';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle` 
    body {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
`; 

export default GlobalStyle;
```

[ package.json ]

```
{
  "name": "dev-lio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

[ login.jsx ]

```
import React from 'react'
import GlobalStyle from '../../components/GlobalStyle';
import GlobalFonts from '../../fonts/fonts'
import LoginForm from '../../components/LoginForm';

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <LoginForm />
            <GlobalFonts />
            <GlobalStyle />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

[ index.jsx ]

```
import React from 'react'
import GlobalStyle from '../../components/GlobalStyle';
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import Profile from '../../components/Profile';
import GlobalFonts from '../../fonts/fonts';

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Profile />
            <GlobalFonts />
            <GlobalStyle />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

It is in the above two files where GlobalStyle is used.

Comment: check this out https://styled-components.com/

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya Checking the documentation, I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Instead, I added the contents of the file using the component that caused the error to the post. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
```

This import tag would imply that createGlobalStyle was not exported as default.
If you try to import a named value as default it will throw an error.

```
import createGlobalStyle from 'styled-components'
```

would be the correct usage for a default export

You could also try module.export, But I have never needed to use this in react. and most of the time the issue is in how I have implemented default/named imports

Comment: Thanks for the advice first. But even if I modify the contents with the code you gave me, the same error occurs in the same part...

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't realize this was a dependency, It looks like you installed it as a dev dependency, If I were you I would try and re-install this package using the tag line found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components. and if that doesn't work then I would double check that I've installed the package into the right directory and if it still doesn't work I would make sure the version of the package doesn't have any bugs or is compatible with my react versions or something along those lines

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. I will try the methods you have given me slowly. Thank you!!!